# Выдает ошибку с REST api и Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, rest

Всем привет, работаю в Node.js и хотел бы использовать REST api, но у меня выдает ошибку при вызове.

*Ошибка такая: Cannot POST /inside*

У меня есть файл с именем Route. В котором я реализую запрос, который после передают на сервер, где он и вызывается. Тут, я реализую один обычный запрос, который должен появится на странице и другой для выбора ID, чтобы передать его как API и пишу чтобы вызывали страницу как inside/:id , но у меня выдает ошибку. (Это POST запрос)

```
const post_inside = (req, res) => {
    var config = {
        user:'postgres',
        database:'my',
        password: '1',
        host:'localhost',
        port:5432,
        max:10,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    }
    var pool = new pg.Pool(config)

    pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
        if(err){
            return console.error('error')
        }
client.query('select * from table1 ($1,$2)',[req.body.login,req.body.date], function(err, result){
return_data.discipline =result 
if (err){
res.end()
return console.error("error")
} 

//2 HERE
client.query("select id from table3 where phone=$1",[req.body.login], function(err, result){
    return_data.id =result 
    if (err){
    res.end()
    return console.error("error")
    }

 res.render('inside/:id',{discipline:return_data.discipline,id:return_data.id})
    })})}}


module.exports = {
    post_inside
}
```

server:

```
app.post('/inside/:id',urlencodedParser,db.post_inside)
```

Я, хочу выбирать тот же файл но уже с API например как: inside/25124

Comment: `Cannot POST /inside` такое ощущение, что ваше приложение вообще игнорирует `app.post('/inside/:id',urlencodedParser,db.post_inside)`.

Вы либо попробуйте максимально упростить функцию db.post_inside, чтобы понять, а выполняется ли она вообще. Ну или точку останова поставьте.

Comment: @ДенисСтепанов Если я просто сделаю вызов `/inside` вместо `/inside/:id` то она открывается без проблем

Comment: какой HTTP-код возврата?